# Why is Magento still showing old version in backend after installing Patch?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, supee-11086

I installed the Patch **SUPEE-11086** but my Magento Version still shows `1.9.4.0` instead of `1.9.4.1`

**Why is the version not changed?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The patches are meant to be applied on older versions to only **fix specific issues** without updating Magento. As such, they do not increase the Magento version number like (1.9.4.0).

If you are already on the latest version you can update Magento with a patch release like 1.9.4.1 **instead** of applying the patch with the shell script.

**The difference is**:

*- an update replaces all core files and bumps the version number 

- a patch only changes specific lines in specific files*

Comment: So how can I upgrade from 1.9.4.0 to magento 1.9.4.1 ? Do I just have to download 1.9.4.1 and copy it over my project?

Comment: Yes first backup your files and database after latest magento 1.9.4.1 files override

Answer (score 0):

Magento version remains unchanged. Only if you update Magento your version gets changed. To confirm whether patch applied successfully or not please visit the file `app/etc/applied.patches.list`